# Different Colored Comments

Tags: r, colors, rstudio, comments

Simple question about comment code aesthetics (color):
I recently noticed in someone's comment code that part of their comment color changed while using the `@` symbol. After experimenting with it, I noticed you also need to have an apostrophe (`'`) right after the octothorp (`#`) as such:

```
#' @text 
      ^--- This turned orange!
```

Since I'm a detailed commenter, I'd love to step things up if I could by adding color to my comments. I know part of the reason is my global IDE (RStudio) options, but I'd never seen anything change a comment's color before, so I was just curious:

1. Why does this occur? I've only seen `@` used when handling large, more-complex objects that need further specification  =>  Ex.  `LargeObject@data$variable`
2. Are there other symbols that trigger a color change?  There's quotes of course (`""`), but quotes do not change color when they're commented out with an octothorp (`#`).
3. Also, on the image (bottom row), is there possibly a way to start and end a comment, followed by a command, all on one line?   => Ex.  `#comment# print(summary(df))`

[image: Basic Examples of Comment Code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The special highlighting you're seeing — words being highlighted after `#' @` — is specific to [roxygen markup](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html) (a documentation-generation system for R). I don't know why that category doesn't seem to be listed/themeable (see #2).
2. The RStudio syntax highlighting colours are [customizable](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html) (you can [edit these themes visually](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai)), but based on what's documented at the link, there appears to be only one category for "comments".
3. This question has to do with the R parser, not the RStudio highlighting system. So the answer is "no"; everything from the first `#` on a line to the line break is considered a comment, no exceptions. **In principle** you could adjust the RStudio highlighting engine to recognize various delimiters within comments and display material following them differently, but you can't create in-line comments (as you could with `/* */` in C) without modifying the R parser.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Two follow up questions: 

In regards to the link about roxygen markup, I'm reading that these special comments are designed to assist in automating the writing of **.rd files** (which from what I've read is basically a standard for documenting objects in a package). So: (1) is this comment syntax mostly for package developers?
(2) If so, then as long as I'm not needing to generate .rd files for what I'm working on, then using the `#' @`  simply to add more color to my comments is harmless?

Comment: (1) yes (although maybe confusing to your readers if they are experienced R developers)

Comment: Right, well thank you again, Ben, I appreciate it!